# How to get Deep Link Data in iOS objective-c

Tags: branch.io

How do you get the data setup in the dashboard.
I have added a key and a value in "Deep Link Data(Advanced)"
In Branch.io dashboard

Login / Menu: Marketing / Actions / Edit

[image]

I have this in objective-c:

```
Branch *branch = [Branch getTestInstance];   
[branch setDebug];
NSDictionary *params = [branch getLatestReferringParams];
```

I am working in "test" of the dashboard.

Comment: Hi! Could you give some details on what you mean by 'data setup in the dashboard'

Comment: Thanks, see update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alex with Branch here:

The `$` symbol is only used to indicate reserved system control parameters (you can find a list of these parameters [here](https://dev.branch.io/getting-started/configuring-links/guide/)). Since you're setting a custom data key, the `key : value` pair you're using in the example actually just needs to be `myplan : 10`.

Your session initialization snippet is also a bit odd. Would you mind sharing where you found it? We might have some documentation somewhere that's out of date...

```
Branch *branch = [Branch getTestInstance];
[branch setDebug];
[branch initSessionWithLaunchOptions:launchOptions andRegisterDeepLinkHandler:^(NSDictionary *params, NSError *error) {
    if (!error) {
        // params are the deep linked params associated with the link that the user clicked -> was re-directed to this app
        // params will be empty if no data found
        // ... insert custom logic here ...
        NSLog(@"params: %@", params.description);
    }
}];
```

Comment: Thanks. I used the "registerDeepLinkController " and therefore not " initSessionWithLaunchOptions : launch options " . I was just looking for something that would get me the parameters. I should have read Doc. more thoroughly, since I do see that it is through " initSessionWithLaunchOptions " . I read it here: https://dev.branch.io/getting-started/deep-link-routing/advanced/ios/#get-first-referring-params

Comment: Ahh! You're actually not wrong. The `NSDictionary *params = [[Branch getInstance] getFirstReferringParams];` call has basically the same result as `initSessionWithLaunchOptions` (it returns the parameters for the most recent link), but it's designed for use AFTER the session is already started. So they aren't mutually exclusive :)